# how to convert existing java project (data driven, keyword & hybrid framework with jxl data provider) to maven project?

Tags: maven

how to convert existing java project to maven. I don't have clear view about maven. Can you please share any links to refer for step by step process?

Comment: Is it an eclipse java project? If yes, you can right-click the project and then select *Configure*->*Convert to maven project*

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic. Please ask a concrete question.